# Sum number in two different files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have two files of same lenght like:

```
0.99952 0.01
0.98927 0.02
0.98242 0.03
```

and

```
-0.758 0.01
-0.745 0.02
-0.742 0.03
```

I would like to sum the first column numbers and print it in a new file with the same elements alongside in the second column. The output should be:

```
0.24152 0.01
0,24427 0.02
0,24042 0.03
```

I tried with

```
 paste file1 file2 | awk '{print ($1 + $2), $4}' > sum
```

but the output is:

```
 1.00952 0.01
 1.00927 0.02
 1.01242 0.03
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You taking invalid parameter number in awk ($2 instead of $3)

```
$1      $2      $3     $4
0.99952 0.01    -0.758 0.01
0.98927 0.02    -0.745 0.02
0.98242 0.03    -0.742 0.03
```

There is a working example:

```
paste data1 data2 | awk '{print ($1 + $3), $4}'
```

Answer (score 7):

The single `awk` approach:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{print $1+a[FNR],$2}' file1 file2
0.24152 0.01
0.24427 0.02
0.24042 0.03
```